# WiX error: lght0094 unresolved reference to symbol

Tags: user-interface, wix, light

I'm having problems trying to light a .wixobj

I am a beginner with WiX and I was trying to get some code off of **[this](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2014/09/real-world-example-wix-msi-application-installer/)** website to work.

After I made Product.wixobj using the 'candle' command in command prompt, I go to 'light' it and it gives me this error:

*(myDirectory)\Product.wxs(235) : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixUI:WixUI_HK.wxs' in section 'Product:*'.*

The command I used was "*light -ext WixUIExtension Product.wixobj*".

My version of WiX is 3.10.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't linking properly. You need to make wixobj files out of **all** the source files on that page.

You need to run candle on WixUI_HK.wxs, Product.wxs, LicenseAgreementDlg_HK.wxs, ServerDlg.wxs then use light referencing all the obj files you just created to link them all together. You also need to supply `-loc Product_en-us.wxl` to light.exe so it replaces all the !(loc.StringName) stuff in your wxs files.

I would suggest you try using visual studio if you can and make a wixproj and add all these files to the project. Wix will take care of properly building and linking your files together.

The other issue you'll have trying to build this is that you probably don't have an "uberAgent.exe" or the app.ico, BannerTop.bmp, Dialog.bmp, or Eula-en.rtf files.